# Lego EV3 python intellisense not available?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I've gone through the steps to get started with Lego EV3 and python described here: https://education.lego.com/en-us/support/mindstorms-ev3/python-for-ev3 however visual studio code isn't giving me any intellisense into pybricks.

In order to get anything up and running I'm having to constantly reference the pdf documentation.  While that isn't an issue for me personally (2 monitors), it will be come this September when I'm trying to teach a class of 4-6 grade kids how to code on small laptops.

The root of the issue is that deploying the application involves copying all the files onto the robot where pybricks is present and all the imports actually work.  However locally in VSCode none of the imports work properly so there's no autocomplete magic.

Anyone know the best solution for getting autocomplete/intellisense up and working?

Comment: Unless the source code for the EV3 Python library is made available, this is rather difficult. VSCode IntelliSense works by reading the source code for the Python library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install python-ev3dev2 package.
You can check the description at the end of this page:
https://github.com/ev3dev/vscode-hello-python

Answer (score 1):

You will either need the source code or you could write `.pyi` files -- which are basically just typed stub files -- to provide the typing information.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019, simply installing [pybrick stubs](https://github.com/drewwhis/pybricks-stubs) did the job for me:

```
$ pip install pybrick-stubs
```